# Using the script from some particular branch in git

Tags: git, github, gitlab

This question is maybe answered, but I couldn't find it.

I have a branch where I am working on and I didn't finish my work on this branch. Now I need to use prebuilt tool that is on totally different branch.

I don't have that script at all visible on my branch, but I need to run it in order to get something, to continue working on my branch. There are three problems here:

1. I don't want to checkout to another branch. I want to work on my own branch all the time
2. I don't want to commit anything before I finish
3. I want to use something from another branch that is not visible on my own branch

How is that possible and is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to deal with this.  They all boil down to the fact that you're trying too hard, right now.   Take it easier!

Let's start with this: Branches, in Git, are basically irrelevant; what matters are the *commits*.  Commits hold two things: a full snapshot of every file, plus some metadata (information about who made the commit for instance).  We won't go into any further detail here except to note that the contents of any given commit are 100% read-only: *no commit can ever be changed*, not even by Git itself.

When you do work in Git, you start by *extracting* some commit.  That is, you run `git checkout branch` or `git switch branch`, or maybe even `git checkout hash-ID`.  This extracts, from one specific commit, a full copy of every file.  (The files stored inside commits are in a special, read-only, compressed, Git-ified, de-duplicated format that only Git can read and literally nothing can write, which makes them useless *except* for this extraction process.)  But: which commit does this extract?

Commits are identified by hash ID.  The hash IDs are big and ugly and impossible for humans to work with, aside from using cut-and-paste with the mouse or similar.  So you can do that—as in the `git checkout hash-ID` case—*or* you can use *branch names* and other such names (tag names for instance).  Each name is a way to spell one hash ID without having to type in the raw hash ID.  A branch name essentially "means" *the latest commit on the branch*.

Now that you have the files from that commit, you work on / with them, run `git add` to update the proposed next commit, and run `git commit`, and Git makes a *new* commit and automatically updates the branch name (assuming you're using branch names).  So that's the situation you're in right now:

> I have a branch where I am working on and I didn't finish my work on this branch.

This isn't quite precise.  What you *mean* is: you checked out some particular commit, by branch name, and you started working.  You're not ready to make a new *commit* yet.  You're still "on the branch" (so that any proposed *new* commit that you use to *make* a new commit will update the branch name to remember the new latest commit) and you'd like to stay that way.

> Now I need to use prebuilt tool that is on totally different branch.

Let's make this one more precise as well.  You mean that you want to get at some file (shell script, command, whatever) that's stored in some *other commit*.  The hash ID of that other commit is stored in some other branch name, e.g., `toolbranch`.

#### Why all this matters

You can easily access any single file in any commit using `git show` or `git cat-file -p`.  For instance, if you know the commit hash ID that you need is `a123456` and the path name of the file stored *in* that commit is `tools/sometool.sh`, you can run:

```
git show a123456:tools/sometool.sh
```

and Git will dump the contents of that file, as stored *in* that commit, to the standard output.  Using shell (bash/sh/zsh/whatever) redirection, you can get this output into a file:

```
git show a123456:tools/sometool.sh > /tmp/sometool.sh
```

and now you can run the tool from `/tmp/sometool.sh`.

(The `git cat-file -p` variant is:

```
git cat-file -p a123456:tools/sometool.sh > /tmp/sometool.sh
```

The `git show` one is a little easier to type in.  Use `git cat-file` in scripts as it's a "plumbing" command; for normal human commands, use `git show`.)

#### What if I don't know the raw hash ID?

No problem!  The branch name works just as well:

```
git show toolbranch:tools/sometool.sh > /tmp/sometool.sh
```

#### What if I need a whole bunch of files from `toolbranch`?

As long as your Git is at least version 2.5, and preferably at least 2.15, you can use `git worktree add` to add a *whole separate working tree* with that commit checked out:

```
git worktree add ../toolbranch
```

for instance.  Now `../toolbranch` contains the entire set of files extracted from the commit named via the branch name `toolbranch`.

Given that this gets *every* file out of the desired commit, it may be overkill for your situation.  The `git show` or `git cat-file -p` variant is a much more refined tool (a [lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber), or maybe bytesaber, instead of a blaster, in Star Wars terms), but sometimes just blasting your way through something is convenient.

(Use `git worktree remove` later to discard the added work-tree, or just leave it around if it isn't bothering you.  The bug fixed in 2.15 has to do with leaving added working trees around for more than 14 days while doing work in them, so if you start doing work *in* the added working tree, and are going to let it take two or more weeks, make sure you have the fixed-up Git.)

Comment: `git show a123456:tools/sometool.sh` : here is the assumption that tools was a sibling folder of the .git folder when commit a123456 was pushed/made? That is, every path git sees is a relative path starting from the same folder `.git` folder is in.

Comment: @Tryer: yes -- or more precisely, paths are often relative to the top level of the working tree. There are exceptions: sometimes paths are relative to where you are within your existing working tree. The only way to find out is by reading each Git command's documentation to see if it says anything, and if not, trying that particular Git command. But note the pathspec magic `:(top)`, too (see [the gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary)).

Comment: Could you please clarify *where* the entire set of files in commit/branch  toolbranch will be extracted to on my local machine when you say: `git worktree add ../toolbranch` I understand that toolbranch is a branch name and hence it points to a commit at the tip. A first time user's concern could be if this extraction somehow overwrites my current working tree.

Comment: @Tryer: Technically `../toolbranch` is just a path name: that's where to put the added working tree. You can name anywhere in the file system that Git can do a `mkdir`. If you want to check out branch `xyz` in path `/tmp/abc` you would use `git worktree add /tmp/abc xyz`. If you don't include a branch name, Git will take the path name and strip it down to the last component to use as the branch name. The path name you give must not exist now (try it out!).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposed solution:

1. Add your script to `.gitignore` to get it not committed. (If you plan to change it, you can force staging by `git add --force`).
2. When you need to run it, checkout only that file by `git check out <SCRIPT_BRANCH> <SCRIPT_FILE_NAME>`.

By the step 1, the checked out file is not seen as a file to be staged.

Comment: `git checkout scriptbranch -- scriptfile` will leave the file in the index, overriding the `.gitignore` entry. Don't do that. You can use `git restore -W` to extract the file without dropping it into the index, as long as you have Git 2.23 or later, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the commit when your tool has been introduced (using `git log` or `git blame <FILE>`) . You can then use `git cherry-pick` to get this specific commit into your branch. If you don't want to commit these changes to your branch, you can use the `-n` flag:

```
git cherry-pick -n <COMMIT>
```

This brings your tool to the current branch without committing anything. You can execute the script and do what you want. Afterwards you can do `git reset` (unstage the cherry-picked stuff) and delete your files.